# Stored procedure moves too many records from active table to history table

Tags: mysql, powershell

I have made a procedure which inputs inventory information from a PowerShell script to a database.

Everything is executing smoothly except one thing. I need copy the values from one table to another history table whenever I run the script and then delete the older entries from the first table so that it has only the entries from the latest scan of values through the PowerShell script. But when I executed it, only the last entry is present in the first table and rest all the entries are sent back to the history table. This is a logic error.

Can you please correct me so that when I run the script, all the entries just are present in the first table and only the entries from the time I last ran the script goes to the other table? or do I need to create a new procedure for it, which I run only once just before the PowerShell loop is executed?

Stored procedure:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `e_inv`.`insertvalue` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE "insertvalue"(
  IN assetname_in varchar(255),
  IN attributename_in varchar(255),
  IN entry_in varchar(255),
  IN val_in int,
  IN sc varchar(255),
  IN ip varchar(255)
)
BEGIN

DECLARE temp_id INT;
DECLARE temp_u_id INT;

INSERT INTO attribute_value_history
SELECT * FROM attribute_value;

DELETE FROM attribute_value;

SELECT u.u_id INTO temp_u_id
FROM user_system_map u
WHERE u.ip_add=ip;

SELECT a.map_id INTO temp_id
FROM asset_attribute_map a
INNER JOIN asset_master b ON a.asset_id=b.asset_id
INNER JOIN attribute_master c ON a.attribute_id=c.attribute_id
WHERE b.asset_name=assetname_in
  AND c.attribute_name=attributename_in;

INSERT INTO attribute_value (
  map_id,
  entry,
  u_id,
  value_id,
  scan_time
) VALUES (
  temp_id,
  entry_in,
  temp_u_id,
  val_in,
  cast(sc as datetime)
);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

PowerShell code:

```psh
cls
$MySQLAdminUserName = 'root'
$MySQLAdminPassword = 'root'
$MySQLDatabase = 'e_inv'
$MySQLHost = 'egovpc3'
$ConnectionString = "server=" + $MySQLHost + ";port=3306;uid=" +
                    $MySQLAdminUserName+ +   ";pwd=" + $MySQLAdminPassword +
                    ";database="+$MySQLDatabase

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$Connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$Connection.Open()

$SqlCommand = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand

$arr=get-content -path "D:\Powershell\New Folder\a.txt"
foreach($comp in $arr) {
  $ip=([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($comp) |select $_.ToString)

  $count=0
  $bios=gwmi Win32_UserAccount -computername $comp -authentication packetprivacy 
  # $date = Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss"
  # $date
  foreach($obj in $bios) {
    $count=$count+1
    $Manufacturer=$obj.Manufacturer
    $Name=$obj.Name
    #$ReleaseDate=$obj.ConvertToDateTime($obj.ReleaseDate)
    #$SerialNumber=$obj.SerialNumber
    #$Version=$obj.Version           
    $date = Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    $date

    $SqlCommand.CommandText = 
      "call insertvalue('UserAccount','Name','$Name','$count','$date','$ip')"
    $SqlCommand.Connection = $Connection

    $SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  }
}
```

**Edit:** I would also like to know how to deploy a `ROLLBACK` statement for this procedure if anything goes wrong and the history is not saved.

Answer (score 0):

Your active table retains only the last record, because you call the stored procedure multiple times in a loop, so that each time all currently existing records (including the ones added in the previous iteration) are moved to the history table. Ergo yes, you should split your stored procedure in two: one for moving existing records to the history table (which you call just once before starting the loop), and the other for adding new records to the active table (which you call inside the loop).

As for being able to roll back an operation: you need to encapsulate the statements in a transaction:

```psh
...
$Connection.Open()

$IsolationLevel = [System.Data.IsolationLevel]::ReadCommitted
$Transaction = $Connection.BeginTransaction($IsolationLevel)

$SqlCommand = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$SqlCommand.Connection  = $Connection
$SqlCommand.Transaction = $Transaction
...
$SqlCommand.CommandText = "..."
$SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
...
$Transaction.Commit()
...
```

To roll back the transaction use `$Transaction.Rollback()` instead of `$Transaction.Commit()`, e.g. in an exception handler:

```psh
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
try {
  $Transaction = $Connection.BeginTransaction($IsolationLevel)
  ...
  $Transaction.Commit()
} catch {
  $Transaction.Rollback()
}
```